# PHP redirect not working in Firefox 24.0

Tags: php, firefox, redirect

I'm developing a site that requires a log in.  I have setup index.php to check if the client is logged in with a session cookie; if not, it redirects to login.php that handles the login logic.  When the user enters their credentials into the login form, it posts to login.php which does the authentication.  If it's okay, it should redirect back to index.php which does most of the work.  This whole setup works perfectly well in Internet Explorer 10 and Chrome 30.  However, in Firefox 24, the initial redirect from index.php to login.php works just fine, but not the redirect from login.php to index.php; all I get is a blank page.  The weird part is, though, that if I try to "view page source" in Firefox, I get "document expired" in the code view window.  When I click try again, the source code pops up as if it had successfully redirected to index.php.

I'm pretty sure this is not a phantom whitespace problem because it works in Chrome and IE, and it did work in a previous Firefox (not to mention that it works if viewing the page source).  Any advice would be appreciated.  Below is a snippet of login.php that does the redirect.

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $contents=tnRequest(...);  // this gets an XML document describing the user
  $xml=simplexml_load_string($contents);
  if($xml->STATUS==0) {
    if($xml->PASSCHANGE==1) { // force a password change
        include('header.php');
        passwdform($puser,$ppass);
        include('footer.php');
        exit;
    }
    // user logged in okay, no forced password change.
    // load data into session variable and redirect to index.php
    load_user_data($xml);
    header('Location: ./index.php');
    exit;
  } else {  // login failed, try again
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    include('header.php');
    echo "<Center><font color='red'><strong>Incorrect login, please try again.</font></center>";
    loginform();
    include('footer.php');
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try updating your header call to remove the . from in front of '/index.php'. I don't see anything immediately obvious here.

Comment: so does it actually enter your condition(s) at all? and if so, did you debug to see where the execution ends? checked Apache logs? can you let's say reproduce it here using same code and browser: http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: What other headers are being output? Are you requiring that the "secure" page(s) be re-created every view or are they being cached?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter If I replace the header call with print_r($_SESSION), it prints out the expected session variable, so execution is getting to that point.  It also works in IE and Chrome.  There are no errors in Apache or PHP logs, and in the Apache access log, it just has a post to login.php, but nothing for index.php

Comment: @Jasper Here are other headers (although I have to admit I didn't set up PHP or Apache so I don't know if they are right).  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: ./index.php
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: @Andrew I could believe that `Content-Length: 0` is your issue, you're instructing the browser to download no content (I believe). It could be that Firefox is the only browser to respect this header. I'm not very familiar with the header but it seems like that's a good thing to look into. Also to force not caching the page, I believe you should add an `Expires` header that is set to a date in the past.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect answer unfortunately.

I have had many issues with PHP redirects in the past.  I have since switched to a javascript redirect which serves the same purpose but avoids all of the header hassles. Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $contents=tnRequest(...);  // this gets an XML document describing the user
  $xml=simplexml_load_string($contents);
  if($xml->STATUS==0) {
    if($xml->PASSCHANGE==1) { // force a password change
        include('header.php');
        passwdform($puser,$ppass);
        include('footer.php');
        exit;
    }
    // user logged in okay, no forced password change.
    // load data into session variable and redirect to index.php
    load_user_data($xml);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    window.location = "./index.php"
    //-->
    </script>
    <?php
    exit;
  } else {  // login failed, try again
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    include('header.php');
    echo "<Center><font color='red'><strong>Incorrect login, please try again.</font></center>";
    loginform();
    include('footer.php');
    exit;
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work then the issue is probably in the address of index.php (try /index.php instead of ./index.php or even index.php, it depends on the location of your web root).  If not you must have a space or some html characters present which is blocking PHP from sending headers.

Good luck!

Comment: What if the user disabled JS?

Comment: If the system that he is working with allows disabled javascripts (which is highly unlikely), then this answer would not be complete.  I mentioned it was an indirect answer.

Comment: JS is definitely a requirement for our site, so this might work.

Comment: a solution for JS-disabled browsers would be to use META redirect in addition to JS redirect when required